# Is it possible to provide dynamic parameters for Java validation?

Tags: java, validation

For this class:

```
class ClassA {
  @FancyValidation
  String value;
}
```

I provide a Validator:

```
public class FancyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FancyValidation, String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return doSomeFancyThingsWithValue(value);
    }
}
```

Is there any way of providing ***dynamically*** some parameters for the validation?

I can add a parameter in the declaration of the constraint, like:

```
@FancyValidation(param1 = "value1")
```

But this is not dynamic.

I could maybe use groups, but as far as I understand I can only "turn on and off" the whole constraints depending on what groups I use.

Is there a way of doing something like this?

```
int parameter1 = 15;
validator.validate(instanceOfClassA, parameter1);
```

that would lead to:

```
public class FancyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FancyValidation, String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        //retrieve somehow the value of parameter1;
        return doSomeFancyThingsWithValue(value, parameter1Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible if you're required to use annotations; annotation parameters must be compile-time constants. You could do it in other ways, such as creating a Map of Field objects (obtained by reflection) with a Map of dynamic validation functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I kind of "hoped" that you could add parameters to the ConstraintValidationContext from outside or provide your own.

Answer (score 0):

i have anothor way, hope can help you.

```
public class User {
String name;
int age;

// just for validate
String value;

@AssertTrue(message = "name not equal value")
private boolean isNameEquals() {
    return Objects.equals(name, value);
}
```

}

you can test like this:

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("name1");
user.setValue("name2");
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> validate = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(user);
System.out.println(validate);
```

Comment: @AssertTrue

 import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue;

Comment: sure, that's a kind of workaround I MIGHT be using, but if the "value" that is relevant for the validation belongs to a parent of a parent of the object I'm validating, it would be ugly to pass it down to the very object. Although not completely impossible:D